# Transport mode encrypted IPSec packet through IPSec Tunnel

Tags: encryption, tunnel, ipsec

We are trying to route transport mode encrypted IPSec packets through a IPSec Tunnel on a Linux Machine.

There are two IPSec entries in tables.
So when original packet is sent to transport IPSec encryption, it matches with first entry (transport mode IpSec) and route the packet out to destination.

What we require is that this IPSec packet to go through Tunnel mode IPSec.

Answer (score 0):

I have not done that setup, why do you need it?

I would try:

1. Set up the tunnel between the networks with internal IPs.
2. Attach the Transport link to internal IPs on the hosts.

This way the Transport packages should go over the Tunnel.